# Cannot write to web.config on shared test server(live)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I want to encrpty my web.config file after I have published to the live test Server. So I have a C# method in my API that I call through fiddler once and it should encrypt as tested on localhost. However when I publish my website and execute the same encryption call it fails with the following error:

> "An error occurred loading a configuration file: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed. (machine.config)"

I have full access permmission to the wwwroot that I am publishing to. I tested this by writing a .txt file to the directory and deleting it.

Since I cannot debug on the live box, I have been throwing exceptions in my DoEncryption class and I have my suspicion on the following code but don't know what to change since it works fine on localhost:

```
               var exeConfigName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Web.config";
           Open the configuration file and retrieve the connectionStrings section.
           Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exeConfigName);//suspect here!!!
           throw new Exception("after connection open");//i do not get this message possibly because of the above line of code
```

Any help or pointers to it

Comment: does the app pool account have write access? not just your account.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is your path is invalid:

```
var exeConfigName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Web.config";
```

Will probably resolve into

```
Path\DirectoryNameWeb.config
```

try using:

```
var exeConfigName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory ,"Web.config");
```

This will basically do:

```
var exeConfigName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Web.config";
```

I can't test it right now, but see if it helps!

Comment: This should be a comment since you are guessing.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was going to say the same but the poster doesn't have the rep to comment and it's arguably too long for a comment.

Comment: @Basic: Do we just leave it alone then?

Comment: I apologise for that, first time poster. Will read the rules in detail asap!

Comment: NathanOliver I was undecided  so I lurked waiting to see what happened... @HotTowelie Not to worry, it takes a while to find your way around. As a rule though, comments are for seeking clarification, answers are for answers. Yours is borderline IMHO.

Comment: I upvoted it to help him get some rep. It's a good guess, and a little rep for people that post thoughtful answers is good for everyone.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! So if I have an answer to a question in which i am fairly certain but not 100% without clarification, and I do not have 50 rep to leave a comment, what should i do?

Comment: The official stance is "Earn 50 rep with things you are certain of first". As you can see from this answer, 50 rep isn't that hard to achieve (5 upvotes on your answers will do it). Unfortunately, we need to do this to control spam levels. Clearly you're not here to spam so I'm doing the same as  @BillGregg to help you on your way. Incidentally, a lot of SO features [work this way](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). The more rep you have, the more trusted you are, the more you can do.

Comment: Thank you once again for the clarification!